# How to query parent based on subdocument's _id?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

consider the following records:

**user record**

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("5234ccb7687ea597eabee677"),
"class" : [
         { "_id" :  ObjectId("5234ccb7687ea597eabee671", "num" : 10, "color" : "blue" },
         { "_id" :  ObjectId("5234ccb7687ea597eabee672", "num" : 100, "color" : "blue" }
       ]
}
```

this user has two class sub records, now **I  need a query that finds all users that have class property where "class._id" has a value of at least one users "class._id"**

here is a more detail example:

suppose there is four user:

```
A:{_id:432645624232345,class:[{_id:123,name:'foo'}]}
B:{_id:432645624232555,class:[{_id:555,name:'foo'},{_id:123,name:'foo'}]}
C:{_id:432645344232345,class:[{_id:555,name:'foo'},{_id:111,name:'www'}]}
D:{_id:432644444232345,class:[{_id:222,name:'sss'},{_id:555,name:'www'},{_id:123,name:'foo'}]}
```

now if B login , I need to query all the user whose class subdocument contains at least one document which's _id==555 or _id==123 (555 and 123 come from B user), in this case the query result should be:

```
A:{_id:432645624232345,class:[{_id:123,name:'foo'}]}  // match _id=123
B:{_id:432645624232555,class:[{_id:555,name:'foo'},{_id:123,name:'foo'}]} //match _id=123 and _id=555
C:{_id:432645344232345,class:[{_id:555,name:'foo'},{_id:111,name:'www'}]}  //match _id=555
D:{_id:432644444232345,class:[{_id:222,name:'sss'},{_id:555,name:'www'},{_id:123,name:'foo'}]}  ///match _id=123 and _id=555
```

which is all the user.

so far i get this:

```
{"class._id" : { $in : ["5234ccb7687ea597eabee671", "5234ccb7687ea597eabee672"] } }
```

but when different user login the class._id query condition is different. So is there any operator to do this

```
{"class._id" : { $in : req.user.class } }
```

hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve what you want, first you must isolate the class _ids in an array, and then use it in the query argument.

```
var classIds = [];
var i = 0;
while (i < req.user.class.length) {
    classIds.push(req.user.class[i]._id);
    i++;
}
```

After that you can use classIds array in the query:

```
{"class._id" : { $in : classIds } }
```

Comment: yes this works, but I was wondering if there is a build in method to achieve this in mongodb?

Comment: The closest to a built in method for that is maybe this: `{"class._id" : { $in : req.user.class.map(function(item) {  return item._id; })} }`

Answer (score 0):

The following query condition  would give you all the users that have at least one class with id equal to any of the elements in the given array:

```
{"class._id" : { $in : ["5234ccb7687ea597eabee671", "5234ccb7687ea597eabee672"] } }
```

In the array for the `$in` clause you may provide any id's you needed , comma separated.

In addition, if you needed such, the below query condition should check for existence of nested document within "class" property that has a property "_id" :

```
{ "class._id" : { $exists : true } }
```

Both conditions should work no matter if `"class._id"` is a single-valued property or an array (mongo supports that).

Comment: it look like it will return all the user!

Comment: Are you looking for particular subclass id or there should just be a subdocument with id ?

Comment: suppose user.class = [{_id:123},{_id:321}],I need to find all the user that user.class = [{_id:123}] or user.class = [{_id:321}] or user.class = [{_id:123},{_id:321}]

Comment: Thx for reply - what if there would be a user with user.class = [{_id:445, 889}] - should this record be included in the result set ?

Comment: no, it should not. sorry for my poor English. I think I did not describe the problem clearly

Comment: yes the $in operator is what i have so far, but do I really have to manually provide the id array { $in : ["5234ccb7687ea597eabee671", "5234ccb7687ea597eabee672"] }, is there a way to do this { $in : user.class }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69015/discussion-between-t-g-and-paynestrike).